# Zend Framework 2: multiple routes to one action

Tags: php, routes, get, zend-framework2

Is there a better solution for doing the following in Zend Framework 2:

I need these two URL's go to one action - help/section/5 and help/section.php?id=5

I think this way is too complicated:

```
        'helpSection' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/help/section/:id',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Help',
                    'action'     => 'section',
                ),
            ),
        ),
        'helpSection2' => array(
            'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Segment',
            'options' => array(
                'route'    => '/help/section.php',
                'defaults' => array(
                    'controller' => 'Application\Controller\Help',
                    'action'     => 'section',
                ),
            ),
            'child_routes'  => array(
                'query' => array(
                    'type' => 'Zend\Mvc\Router\Http\Query',
                    'options' => array(
                        'defaults' => array(
                            'id' => ':id'
                        )
                    )
                ),
            ),
        ),
```

Comment: you could always use rewrite as an alternative and keep that stuff out of your codebase.
pretty simple to rewrite urls with an extension (.php) to the url without the extension.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this might actually work... It should match the following:

- /help/section
- /help/section?queryString
- /help/section.php
- /help/section.php?queryString
- /help/section/1
- /help/section/1?queryString

this would be the config:

```
'type' => 'segment',
'options' => array(
    'route' => '/help/section[(.php|/:id)]',
    'defaults' => array(
        'controller' => '...',
        'action' => '...'
    ),
    'constraints' => array(
        'id' => '[0-9]+'
    )
),
'may_terminate' => true,
'child_routes' => array(
    'query' => array(
        'type' => 'query'
    )
)
```

Comment: Hmm, too bad, i'll check back tomorrow and eventually edit if i get it working, was worth the shot :P